# How to copy files by value and not reference in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have been struggling for a while. When I move files to a project, and then delete those files. The files in the project also get deleted. Why? And how can i copy the files, and not just the reference? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

while copying or moving files make sure you checked the button : "Copy items if needed" like below image

[image]